# tomcat management interface gives 403 forbidden error

Tags: tomcat8

I've had to configure two tomcat servers recently. I've setup one tomcat server using using version 8.5.13 and that works fine. I can access Server Status, Manager App and Host Manager web interfaces with no problem.

But when I tried setting up a new tomcat server running tomcat version 8.5.14 by copying the same configs from the from the 8.5.13 server I'd built I get access denied 403 on the Server Status and Manager app. But oddly only the Host Manager web interface works correctly. I can access that.

I need to figure out why the same configs that work on the first server, give me 403 denied on the second server.

This is what I have on each:

Working server Java:

```
java version "1.8.0_121"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)
```

Non working server have a newer java:

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
```

Everything else is identical in terms of configuration.

Both have java and tomcat variables setup in /etc/profile:

```
JAVA_HOME='/usr/lib/jvm'
CATALINA_HOME='/usr/local/tomcat'

export PATH USER LOGNAME MAIL HOSTNAME HISTSIZE HISTCONTROL JAVA_HOME CATALINA_HOME
```

Both servers have the same config files, copied from the 1st working server to the 2nd non working server.

Tomcat users config:

```
cat /usr/local/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml
<tomcat-users>
    <user username="admin" password="not_saying" roles="manager-gui,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

The context configuration file has this:

```
 cat /usr/local/tomcat/conf/context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- The contents of this file will be loaded for each web application -->
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<!--  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
               allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /> -->
</Context>
```

And the webapps context.xml config for both tomcats has this:

```
cat /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/host-manager/META-INF/context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
  Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
  contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
  this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
  The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
  (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
  the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

  Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
-->
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
<!--  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
               allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1" /> -->
</Context>
```

Why is tomcat server 1 (version 8.5.13) working and the newer tomcat version (8.5.14) on server 2 not working?

Answer (score 1):

Can you verify that you're trying to access this from a machine other than localhost AND that you haven't commented out the RemoteAddrValve restriction in manager/META-INF/context.xml? You show a snippet from the host-manager's context.xml with it commented out and say you can access host-manager, but didn't really confirm that you did the same for the manager webapp.